# Setting TextView in Another Class

Tags: java, android

I have researched many problems like mine on the internet and none seem to be doing what I'm trying to do. What I am trying to do is get a textview that is currently blank in my high_risk.xml file, and make it have text based on if a button is clicked in another class. Here is what I have so far...

Question13Activity(if the yes button is clicked I want to be able to set the text in the HighRisk Activity)

```
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finalYes);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("New Text");
            t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abusedOrNah);
            t.setText(text);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Question13Activity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

This is how I have the static variable t defined in my highrisk activity class...

HighRiskActivity(this is where I want the text to be set and displayed)

```
public static TextView t;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.high_risk);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(HighRiskActivity.this, Question12Activity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("Text", "New Text");
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

Every time I try and access the contents of t in another class and change it's text, it always returns null. Any way I can fix this from happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: instead of using it as static variable , send it in a bundle with intent

Comment: could you show an example of that, I'm not too sure what that is... I've seen it in other SO posts but was never sure what it really did. I'm still a beginner ;D

Comment: can you please add complete code (and xml ) with activity names , also if you are trying to start Question13Activity activity with intent , why need to set textview of HighRiskActivity ?

Comment: Once the button in the activity is clicked I need it to generate text at the end of a different activity

Comment: please mention to which activity 1st snippet belongs....its not clear , please mention the names from which activity to which you want to move and to which the textview belong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bounds, to get the the data to the new Activity and set the text from there:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Question13Activity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("<KEY-NAME>", "<TEXT>");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

And in the Question13Activity.class:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text= intent.getStringExtra("<KEY-NAME>");

t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abusedOrNah);
t.setText(text);
```

UPDATE:

Use it so:

HighRiskActivity.class:

```
 yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finalYes);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Question13Activity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("TestKey", "My new Text");
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Question13Activity.class:

```
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.high_risk);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text= intent.getStringExtra("TestKey");

t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abusedOrNah);
t.setText(text);
```

Comment: The top code snippet I would put in my HighRisk activity(which is where I want the text to be set and displayed) And the bottom code snippet would be put in my Question13Activity class?

Comment: Yes, and <TEXT> is the text you want in the TextView

Comment: Just to clarify, what does <KEY-NAME> mean?

Comment: <KEY-NAME> is a String to know in the other Activity from which Intent Extra to get the string. This can any word but it must be the same at both activitys

Comment: I am still getting a null pointer error :( I'm going to update my code in my question

Comment: I have updated the full code for you and pls do not change the orginal question, add only a new update section (like me)

Answer (score 0):

In order to `setText()` from another class (for example, from your Custom class), you need to specify the activity on which you'd like to do that.

Unless a class does have a reference of your context, you cannot call 'findViewById()'

To do that, you use Context as a parameter for custom class constructor.

Just after you have set the context will you be able to call

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.text);
        txtView.setText("foo");
}
```